# bash: redirecting standard input to a file

Tags: bash, stdin, zsh, io-redirection, stdio

`zsh` has this handy functionality where one can pipe stdin to a file using

```
>file
```

What is the `bash` equivalent to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the post from @chepner for a full explanation of how `zsh` does this.  The equivalent in bash is:

```
cat > file
```

Alarm bells ring whenever we see `cat`, it is [often abused](http://www.smallo.ruhr.de/award.html) yet this is a legitimate use of the program.  Strictly speaking only the redirection part `> file` is bash, `cat` itself is an independent program.

Answer (score 3):

The meaning of `> file` in `zsh` depends on how certain options are set. If `SH_NULLCMD` is set, then it is equivalent to `: > file`, which would be the equivalent command in any `sh`-derived shell, `bash` included.

See `man zshmisc` under the heading `REDIRECTIONS WITH NO COMMAND` for more details.

UPDATE: I'm completely mistaken. Setting `SH_NULLCMD` changes the meaning of `> file` altogether, making `> file` equivalent to `: > file` in `bash` rather than `: > file` in `bash` being equivalent to the default behavior of `> file` in `zsh`.

As cdarke pointed out (and he should post the answer), the correct equivalent in `bash` is `cat > file`.

Comment: Are you saying that `: > file` reads from `stdin` in bash?  Surely it's `cat > file`?